# Section of Importing functions in Haskell is called?

Tags: haskell

As we import other modules in Haskell by using **import** key word. It is the first section in the Haskell file then the body section starts. Can anyone tell me the name of **importing modules section**?

```
import Hugs.Prelude    
import Char
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Haskell 2010 Language Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-980005) just calls it a "list of import declarations".

Also, there are at least two (optional) sections that commonly come earlier: a list of language extension pragmas, and the module header with the export list.